# React useContext not triggering rerender in child after provider state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm having trouble getting my child component to rerender when using a context provider. Logging the listener output shows that the AuthContextProvider component does successfully update and connect to the authentication service, but the child App component does not rerender - the screen shows that I am not logged in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

AuthContext.tsx:

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/firebaseConfig';

export type AuthContextProps = {
    user: firebase.User | null;
    authenticated: boolean,
    setUser: any,
    loadingAuthState: boolean
}

const defaultAuthContext: AuthContextProps = {
    user: null,
    authenticated: false,
    setUser: null,
    loadingAuthState: true
}

let AuthContext = createContext(defaultAuthContext);

const AuthProvider = (props: any) => {

    const AuthContext = React.createContext<Partial<AuthContextProps>>({});
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null as firebase.User | null);
    const [loadingAuthState, setLoadingAuthState] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchUser = async () => {
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore();
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('test@gmail.com', 'gympass').then(val => val.user);
        }

        fetchUser().then(() => {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
                setUser(user)
                console.log('LOGGED IN')
                setLoadingAuthState(false)
            });
        });

    }, [])

    const value = {
        user,
        authenticated: user !== null,
        setUser,
        loadingAuthState
    }

    console.log('VALUE:', value)

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;
export {AuthContext, AuthProvider, AuthConsumer}
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {AuthContext} from './context/AuthContext';
import {AuthContextProps} from "./context/AuthContext";

function App() {

  const auth: AuthContextProps = useContext(AuthContext)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>You are currently {auth.user === null ? 'not ' : ''}logged in.</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {AuthProvider} from './context/AuthContext'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthProvider>
          <App />
      </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: You are calling `createContext` twice for `AuthContext`. Have you spotted that?

Comment: Clearly it's been a long day - that was the issue! Thanks for your help. @Enijar

Comment: No worries, we all have those days